# Extract Text From SVG

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, arrays

a codepen demo [here](https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/QWBBxze?editors=1000) is a SVG bitmap code, I plan to extract the text from an SVG file instead of an image (PNG or JPG file) because SVG image quality is extremely good. This Image to Text (OCR) codepen demo [here](https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/MWBBeLO) is able to extract text from an image. Thus, I was wondering how do I actually **extract text from SVG file b**ecause SVG file for text is more preferable than PNG or JPG file for text ?

I have searched for svg to text converter on the web, for example, [here](https://products.aspose.app/pdf/conversion/svg-to-txt), but it does not provide any API for Javascript? Can anyone show some examples text being extracted from SVG file? Any help is very much appreciated:)

`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="595.2pt" height="841.92pt" viewBox="0 0 595.2 841.92">`

`<g enable-background="new">`

Comment: Just get its `textContent`.

Comment: @Spectric, hello, do you mean that in the SVG code I am able to find the number 91 & 64? Because I couldnt searched any and I believe the are just a very long code which builds the number 91&64 bit by bit :)  ?

Comment: `document.querySelector('svg').textContent`